# Is require() bad practice? How to not reuse code

Tags: php, dry

Is it bad practice using require() a lot? Most websites have a header and a footer that looks the same whereever you navigate on the page. But the main content varies from page to page. And since I don´t want to reuse code, have the same code in two places, I think require() is pretty good. But is it okay using it like I do?

Here´s my example:

```
<div class="content">
    <section>
        <?php require('mainpage.php'); ?>
    </section>
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <?php require('sidebar/box1.php'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar-box">
            <?php require('sidebar/box2.php'); ?>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

A sidebar box is a box that contains stuff like "Latest news" etc. And since I may want to have the "Latest news" box on many pages I need to require() it in order to not have the same code in two places.

Should I solve it someway else?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you can use require_once()  . this will not include the same file if its already being included.

Comment: @rajesh, require_once() should never be used. It's really too much expensive as a function. Benchmarking tests show that `include()` is the fastest.

Comment: it depends upon the situation. in a case where you sud not proceed without includeing the file then require_once is preferred. as it throws error if file not found. and it will not include the file if its laready included. but in case of include if u have included file twice. it will throw error if that file contains any function as that way u r trying to  redefine the function

Comment: Why do you ask? what's the reason you think that require is a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with that at all, it's very good practice to reuse code chunks. It also keep the HTML structure far more readable and gives you some basic separation between HTML presentation and PHP business logic. Check out the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) for why this is a good thing.

Some points to bear in mind:

- You might want to consider using a $docroot variable that has the full server file path, as relative file paths can occasionally go wonky on some PHP installs and also if you include the above  code itself from another file. Relative file paths look like it's easier to move the whole codebase around, but you can just alter $docroot if you do this and it's fine. You could also use a $librarydir variable so that your HTML templates can be moved around without shifting the location of the PHP files.
- Some files ought to be brought it with require_once() so that you don't get a mess e.g. the HTML header, page footer etc. Might sound obvious, but it's easy to put the footer into two files that you then include from somewhere else, so this can make debugging easier by giving a more verbose error message.
- You may find that a templating engine which does the MVC approach in    a more formalised an flexible way could help you. Check out    [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) as others have mentioned, or [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/), which is a PHP5    rewrite of it.
- Odd things can happen if the code in the included files uses variables in the global scope, and as your program becomes more    complex, this can lead to hard-to-pin-down bugs where one include is    subtly breaking another by altering variables with the same name.    Consider putting the code for a sideblock into a function or class so    that variables are in their own scope and you can keep them separate.

Answer (score 4):

That looks totally okay and is exactly what `require()` was built for.

Situations where  using `require()` isn't great practice are usually on the PHP end - e.g.  fetching big blocks of PHP code that are executed straight away. Having a proper library with functions or classes is the better idea in those cases. But fetching repetitive page sections using `require()` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

No, of course not. `require()` is a good practice especially when you want to make some controls before make the user interact with your pages. For instance, you can keep database connection data or user session control data in separate *PHP* files and **require** them before providing your specific pages to the users. In that way, you reuse code and facilitate your work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the principles you're outlining are good ones. It's always good to avoid code duplication and re-use "chunks" like this. I would say that you should avoid re-inventing the wheel. You might want to investigate a templating system to help you manage the "chunks" you're creating to build your site. Rather than try and build one yourself, I would investigate the ones out there already (Twig and Smarty are two that spring to mind, there are others). Even if you decide not to use one, looking at it and seeing how it's put together will help you when you're building your own.

Comment: No you don't NEED templating system. Smarty is what I definitely don't suggest. Use PHP itself please. Do me a favor, let tempting system a part and use things like `<?php echo $var; ?>` or `<?=$var?>` instead of things like `{$var}` that has to be parsed and slow down everything.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli: agree with Jeff. PHP itself is template engine, CMIIW.

Comment: I'd add that Smarty is the one that reinvented the wheel here.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli Ok, maybe "need" was the wrong word, and my post wasn't totally clear. My suggestion into looking at templating systems that are out there was not about the "templating" part of it. Yes, PHP does that itself. Rather it was about how you structure your templates and other functionality that you might want to add to your templates (such as output escaping). Please also note my last line - I was suggesting that the OP might want to roll out his own but looking at some of the "off-the-shelf" systems is a good way to learn how to go about it yourself.

Comment: @liquorvicar, in my honest opinion there's nothing that you cannot do with PHP itself. No need for Smarty & co. at all. But I might be wrong too. Just my opinion.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli I don't completely disagree with you. My point is that there are quite a few subtleties and complexities in how you use your templates that aren't obvious when you're starting out. Looking at (or using) one of the templating frameworks out there helps you discover and solve these issues. Personally I'm not a huge fan of Smarty I do think it's over-engineered. I speak from experience of running a website in PHP that's 12-years old and was never built with internationalisation in mind...

Comment: @liquorvicar, Smarty and any other template-engine brings also cons to your equation: need to parse files with probably the use of regex (more expensive that what you might think) and a lot of code which obliviously leave an open road for bugs. I don't know if it worth the risk... that's all.

Comment: @liquorvicar, I was not attacking you. There are a lot of people that think that big project needs templating system and that the slowness can be lowed caching pages. There are also a lot of people that, for example, use smarty and feel good. I was just pointing out my point of view. That's all. Don't feel attacked. I can get your point of view more than what you think. It's just a matter of choice.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli Yes, of course, there are cons. Trade-offs are part and parcel of the business we're in. As for bugs, there's an argument that says community code with the many developers that use it has less bugs than your own personal code. Either way, I don't think it's a simple question of one way being right and the other wrong. The most important thing IMHO here on SO is to help others and give them the info to make their decisions...